# How do I to map a foreign key column referring two tables?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

In ColdFusion using ORM, how do I to map a foreign key column referring two tables?

My example.

At the moment an Image can belong to either a human or alien

```
Image.cfc
property name="imageID" fieldtype="id" generator="guid";

// Related Object Properties (many-to-one)
property name="Human" fieldtype="many-to-one" fkcolumn="HumanID" cfc="human";
property name="Alien" fieldtype="many-to-one" fkcolumn="AlienID" cfc="alien";
```

This leaves me with a table looking like this..

```
Image.cfc

    ID   NAME    HumanID  AlienID
    1    img1    10       NULL
    2    img2    NUll     8
```

To me NULLs smells bad!

So can I replace this with one mapping for both objects? Or If I create a category table? Any Ideas?

Thanks

Spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't map a single property to more than one parent object. So you have two options here.

You will need to map this as a [class per heirarchy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WS027D3772-2E98-4d5b-8800-054A62EBF8D9.html#WSB268B0CB-17CB-4e28-B0D3-ED72DF166D8E) where you will have classes for HumanImage and AlienImage that extend the base Image class

```
// Image.cfc
component persistent="true" {
    property name="id" generator="guid";
    property name="name";   
}

// AlienImage.cfc & HumanImage.cfc
component persistent="true" extends="Image" joincolumn="id" {
}

// Alien.cfc
component persistent="true"  {
    property name="id" generator="guid";
    property name="Image" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="AlienImage"
      fkcolumn="fkAlienID";
}

// Human.cfc
component persistent="true"  {
    property name="id" generator="guid";
    property name="Image" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="HumanImage"
      fkcolumn="fkHumanID";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Right so I could remove the relationships from image and keep the one-to-many in both Alien and Human. does it matter if the  fkcolumn name for both is the same?

Comment: To explain better, in your example, does it matter if the fkcolumn name for both Alien and Human are the same i.e. ownerId?

Comment: keeping the FK the same gives me an error The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FKC3567ECBC1563EC8". The conflict occurred in database "database"

Comment: This way Image.cfc maintains a single column 'ownerId' which maps to the owning entity. <- this does not seem to work when fkcolumn name is the same in both Alien and Human

Comment: oops, i tested this in a myisam db which doesnt support foriegn keys so it worked ok. I have have changed the answer to illustrate how it can be done and maintain fk's

Comment: wow thats smart nice OO design now. thanks for your help Chris